# nextTrackCommand and seekForwardCommand are both called at the same time

Tags: ios, mpremotecommandcenter

It seems that when I press "next" on control center when playing something (simulator or device), both `nextTrackCommand` and `seekForwardCommand` are getting called.

Both functions are enabled, but it doesn't make sense that both get called upon just tapping the "next" button.

Here's more of the code:

```
[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].playCommand.enabled = YES;
[[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].playCommand addTargetWithHandler:^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent * _Nonnull event) {
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
}];

[[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].nextTrackCommand addTargetWithHandler:^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent * _Nonnull event) {
    NSLog(@"nextTrackCommand");
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
}];
[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].nextTrackCommand.enabled = YES;

[[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].seekForwardCommand addTargetWithHandler:^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent * _Nonnull event) {
    NSLog(@"seekForwardCommand");
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
}];
[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].seekForwardCommand.enabled = YES;
```

I've linked bellow to an example project that demonstrates this issue.

https://github.com/gerbil802/MPRemoteCommandCenterProblem

Comment: I know it's been a while... But did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No. I haven't touched it for a while. Do you know if it still exists in iOS 15.0?

Comment: Yes, I am also still struggling with this issue.